# dkjango ForeignKey that allows Null value

Tags: django

I have class Comment with ForeignKey to self - parent:

```py
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I allowed null and blank enteries, but when i try to create a new comment without a parent, i have this

> log:ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « parent_id »

can someone help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to add `default=None` to the field definition or provide a `parent=None` attribute when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by deleting migration file content!